# Bootstrap NavBar with center aligned items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the left side is my brandname.
I try to center the text and the icons in the navbar. But it is allwys to the left of the brandname.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div style="" class="container-fluid navi">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <p class="navbar-brand brand">Lapsy</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
            <li>Follow us</li> 
            <li><img src="img/f.png" alt="Facebook Fanpage" class="img-responsive">  </li>
            <li><img src="img/t.png" alt="Twitter Fanpage" class="img-responsive">  </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you are more detailed in your problem here. And try to post the CSS to go along with the HTML.

Comment: The css    .navbar {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .5s;
    }
    .opaque {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity .5s;
    }
    
    .navi {
     padding-top: 10px; 
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    }
    .navbar-brand {
     font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive;
     font-weight: 400;
     color: #EA6B3E; 
     font-size: 36px;
    }
    .navbar-nav li  {
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Give `text-align:center` to class navbar-inner and give `text-align:left` to your Brand Name. **Note** I gave `display:inline` property to ul li to put them in a single line. You can see the result here. http://jsfiddle.net/5t5sfx5h/

Comment: Now the text "follow us" is not in the same height as the icons http://jsfiddle.net/5t5sfx5h/3/

Comment: There is nothing visible in your jsfiddle. Check mine, the text "follow Us" appear in the same line as the rest. May be because I haven't used any image yet. If you are using images.  If "follow us" does not appear in the same height as the icons, you can use `vertical-align` property  and increase the `font-size` to fix it. Here I assigned class **follow-us** to `<li>Follow us</li>` and assigned following things to it 
`    font-size:25px;
    vertical-align:top;`
Here you can see the result http://jsfiddle.net/5t5sfx5h/5/